# MSBuild: directory.build.props and directory.build.targets does not work with *.wixproj

Tags: msbuild, wix

directory.build.props and directory.build.targets is not working with Windows Installer Wix projects. *.wixproj

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Background

The implicit import of **directory.build.props** and **directory.build.targets** is an intrinsic feature of MSBuild 15.0+. It does **not** have to be in the new SDK project style format for it to work. The *magic* happens via the import of **microsoft.common.props**, which SDK style projects do automatically and most older style projects include as the first import in the project file. This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2017#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets).

Unfortunately, WiX projects do not include this import, which is why it’s not being picked up (as shown [here](https://github.com/wixtoolset/VisualStudioExtension/blob/develop/src/Templates/v3/Projects/WixProject/SetupProject.wixproj) in the Votive source). I can't say why, but there might be a reason for **microsoft.common.props** being excluded.

Since it's unclear if importing **microsoft.common.props** *may* cause you grief, the recommended approach is the import the extensions manually using the new **GetPathOfFileAbove** function. You only need to do this once.

### Solution

1. Unload your project with **Right-click the project → Unload {name}…**
2. **Right-click the project → Edit {name}…**
3. Add the following at **Line 3** (should be the first element in the `<Project>`):

   ```
   <Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove(directory.build.props))"
           Condition="Exists('$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove(directory.build.props))')" />
   ```
4. Add the following at the bottom of the file **before** the WiX targets are imported:

   ```
   <Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove(directory.build.targets))"
           Condition="Exists('$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove(directory.build.targets))')" />
   ```

> If you need to hook into the WiX build process or targets, use the **CustomBeforeWixTargets** and **CustomAfterWixTargets** build properties, which might refer to the **directory.build.targets** file itself via the **MSBuildThisFileFullPath** reserved property. This will ensure things are imported by WiX at the appropriate time.

After this is configured the use of **directory.build.props** and **directory.build.targets** will be as expected. If WiX ever natively supports these build extensions, you'll be aligned and should be able to remove these explicit imports at your leisure.

Comment: WiX v4 switches to using Microsoft.Common.props.

Comment: Good to know. I am curious though, the project templates for a new _Setup Project_ (\*.wixproj) is shipped as part of the Visual Studio Extension (aka _Votive_) is it not? I still don't see Microsoft.Common.props being brought into the project (REF: https://github.com/wixtoolset/VisualStudioExtension/blob/develop/src/Templates/v4/Projects/WixProject/SetupProject.wixproj) Is this import happening some other way?

Comment: https://github.com/wixtoolset/Tools/blob/master/src/WixToolset.BuildTasks/wix.targets#L75

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. ;)

Comment: It took me a while to figure out why my .targets file wasn't seeing my wixproj properties. It will be nice to have the v4 hooks